# opencv tobytes returns more bytes than expected

Tags: opencv

I have a image frame of dimension say 224 * 224 * 3. After calling the following lines, the size of returned bytes is 150536 (8 more bytes than 224 * 224 * 3). Is this normal?

```
mat = cv2.imdecode(image_frame, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
mat = cv2.resize(mat, (224, 224))
data_frame = mat[:,:,::-1].tobytes()
```

Comment: That is odd. Try checking `mat.size`.

Comment: @MarkSetchell mat.size is fine (150528)

Comment: And `mat[:,:,::-1].size` ?

Comment: @MarkSetchell Same, 150528

Comment: It's a mystery. I would reinstall Numpy, and failing that, Python.

Comment: If you do cv2.imshow does the image look correct?